# Step through page execution with XDebug with Eclipse?

Tags: php, debugging

I am trying to see what happens during the execution of a page.  What should I do to monitor the variables after each step (function call or line execution) of the page running?  How can I control when to take the next step in the execution of the page?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with debugging in Eclipse as I use Netbeans, but I'd assume that the process is rather similar. There's a [good article here](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930) about how to set up Eclipse to use xdebug and an overall introduction to debugging your applications from Eclipse.

One thing to note (at least in the FreeBSD version that I'm running) - adding watches is apparently experimental and might require restarts here and there.

Comment: Yeah that article is good.  It is actually what I've been using to get up and running.  Just somehow not seeing how to actually step through the page execution line by line.  Will look more I guess :)

Comment: Again, not sure about Eclipse, but in Netbeans you can launch a debug Firefox (or whichever browser you have set to use xdebug in config) instance using F6 (I think?). When the request is caught by the FF instance, execution automatically pauses at the first line of code within Netbeans. You can then step through it using F* keys as you would in VS.

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse Menu: Window/Show View/Variables